# Magento 2 Increase guest session time and keep the items in cart for 20 days

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, session, cookie

I want t increase guest user session time in magento. If guest user add to cart and just go for lunch or any other activity putting his/her website open in browser, when user come after 5-6 hours check website after 6-7 days they see their item added to cart in website.

How can we do that?  How can i make persistent guest session so whenever guest customer come to site they see their added product in cart?

Right now if customer come after 4-5 hours cart gets empty.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could enable persistent cart and set the time out there but this will affect customers as well as guests

Comment: Yes, persistent is set but for guest it's getting time out after 3 to 4 hours. while i have entered 2000000000 value means more than a month.  Guest user keep screen ideal for 3 to 4 hour and refresh the page cart items are gone.  So what's the solution?